# Customer_save_after observer - is it an update or a registration?

Tags: magento2.3

I have implemented an observer for `customer_save_after` event. Is there a way to know if it is a new customer registration or an update?

I cannot use the `customer_register_success` event as it is not triggered when the registration/update is done through the **REST API**. I assume that's because it's defined inside `app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

Comment: You are able to check customer email already exist or not. If not customer is new.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to discriminate update and registration to call another API to sync customer's data, whenever a registration or update takes place from magento REST API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

I think `after` event doesn't work for your case. We should use `customer_save_before` and get customer id or email and check if it exists or not by using customer repository.

**Method 2:**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    if($customer->isObjectNew() )
    {
      //new customer
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried $customer->isObjectNew() but never returns true. Am I missing something?

Comment: which event are you using?

Comment: sorry my bad.. you meant when using customer_save_before. its working there.. but I want to add my code after customer is saved. Is there a way to share the information I'm getting from isObjectNew() on the "before" observer with the "after" observer?

Comment: after_save means already customer created here you can't able to check, in before event you can check and set the session variable with customer_id and flag as new. After that, check the session variable in after event and execute your code and unset your session variable.

Comment: Thanks! I used registry to share the data between the observers